# UILabel dotted line color bug in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uilabel

The dotted line at the end of an UILabel is not affected by the textColor.

You will find a sample project here : https://github.com/nverinaud/DottedLineBug.

The code involved is the following :

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:sender.value
                                saturation:1
                                brightness:1
                                     alpha:1];
    self.label.textColor = color;
}
```

Here is a picture showing the issue :
[image]

Does anyone have the same bug and have find a workaround ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried to use NSAttributedString?

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your project, update your question by pasting in the relevant code. Just post the code for the label and the colors.

Comment: You should totally do what Andrea said

Comment: Log a bug report with Apple (http://bugreport.apple.com) and try `NSAttributedStrings` to see if that will work around the problem.

Comment: @maddy: I just did it :)

Comment: NSAttributedString does work, I'll report the bug to apple and keep this thread updated.

Comment: @nverinaud Make sure to add the radar number to the question so people can duplicate it.

Comment: @LeoNatan I have the bug ID (which has already been marked as duplicate by apple) : 16470528. Does this lead to the following rdar URL : rdar://problem/16470528 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `NSAttributedString` does work. (Thanks to [Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395897/andrea)).

Here is an exemple :

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:sender.value
                                saturation:1
                                brightness:1
                                     alpha:1];

    NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color }];

    self.label.attributedText = text;
}
```

I did report to Apple, here is the report ID : `16470528`.

It has already been marked by Apple as a duplicate of `16443091`.